# javascript - Append multiple elements to the <input> tag when focused using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came to [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/google-material-design-input-boxes-in-css3) tutorial site for their awesome Material Design input boxes. The implementation was very easy, but I just don't like the idea of including two `<span>` elements (please do check the [code](http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/IdGKH?editors=010) to know what I'm talkin' about) so instead I like to append those two elements to the `<input>` tag when it is focused with the use of jQuery's `append()` method. But as a newbie to the jQuery world, coding it myself was difficult so I will be needing some help here.

The following example code (below) is what I currently have but they don't work for me.

```
$("input").focus(function() {
  var $elem = '<span class="firstClass"></span>' + '<span class="secondClass"></span>';
  $("input").append($elem);
});
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: appending something to an element that can't contain children doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read your link and the html they are not appending a span in an input which is not possible because input cannot contain children elements in html.
You might mean to append to the parent of the input though and that would be simpler.

```
$("input").parent().append($elem);
```

Comment: Ahh yes thank you for guiding me. I'm just beginning to learn this jQuery library. Case solved.

Comment: Sorry didn't knew that the input can't contain child elements so thank you.

Comment: No problem I wish you luck on your learning endeavors, I recommend a little html classes. http://www.w3schools.com/